# Changing multiple commits with TortoiseGit

Tags: tortoisegit

I am a sole developer and have no worries about anyone else changing my remote repositories.

I have realised that several of my recent commits were wrong:

[image]

All of the `[MSA-27] [MSA-37]` should have been `[MSA-27] [MSA-36]`. These codes are important for Jira Issue board. What is the easiest way to correct all of these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the log dialog, select the last commit that is correct.

Then start a rebase upon this commit.

On the rebase dialog  select "Force" and mark all commits you want to modify as "edit".

Then start the rebase. The process will halt after each commit you marked are "edit" and allows you to modify the commit message (if you also want to modify files in the commits, check "Edit/split commit").

Comment: Thanks. Those instructions made sense. They were to the point and clear. All I had to remember was  to do a push with force for known changes to update the online repository.